# What this function on redraws and reflows is doing?

Tags: javascript, html

The JS code is meant to minimizethe number of redraws and reflows required. I'm quite new to the concept so i'm not to sure what the function is doing....specifically the for loop.

```
(function() { 
    var element, 
        index, 
        length, 
        content = document.getElementById("content"),
        html = "",
        data = [{ 
            id: 1, 
            name: "John", 
            color: "green" 
        }, { 
            id: 2, 
            name: "Sally", 
            color: "pink" 
        }, { 
            id: 3, 
            name: "Andrew", 
            color: "blue" 
        }, { 
            id: 4, 
            name: "Katie", 
            color: "purple" 
        }];

    for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        html +=
            '<li id="' + data[index].id + '" style="color: ' + data[index].color + '">' +
                '<strong>' + data[index].name + '</strong>' +
            '</li>';
    } 

    content.innerHTML = html;
 })();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is simply concatenating strings for each element of the array. The purpose of this is to put all the HTML for the list into a single string, and then put that into the DOM once, rather than appending to the HTML each time through the loop. This is more efficient because the HTML only has to be rendered once instead of multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite in depth.

Answer (score 0):

to see, what is the output:

```js
(function() { 
    var element, 
        index, 
        length, 
        content = document.getElementById("content"),
        html = "",
        data = [{ 
            id: 1, 
            name: "John", 
            color: "green" 
        }, { 
            id: 2, 
            name: "Sally", 
            color: "pink" 
        }, { 
            id: 3, 
            name: "Andrew", 
            color: "blue" 
        }, { 
            id: 4, 
            name: "Katie", 
            color: "purple" 
        }];

    for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        html +=
            '<li id="' + data[index].id + '" style="color: ' + data[index].color + '">' +
                '<strong>' + data[index].name + '</strong>' +
            '</li>';
    } 

    content.innerHTML = html;
 })();
```

```html
<ul id="content">

</ul>
```